# Drawing horizontally/vertically aligned rectangular polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, polygon-creation

I am trying to draw some rectangles in a polygon layer, to be used to highlight points for checking, and will be used in Data Driven Pages.

I want these to be horizontally aligned, however the "Rectangle" Construction Tool uses the direction you start drawing.

[image]

[image]

As a result I have to select the Rectangle construction tool, click on the map to start drawing the polygon, right-click > Direction > `0` to restrict it to drawing east/west (horizontal), and then draw the rectangle.

[image]  [image]

I have many of these I need to draw, so having all these extra clicks and keypresses seems excessive when I just want to draw a rectangle!

[image]

How can I *efficiently* create horizontally aligned polygons in ArcMap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key!

Start editing and choose the Rectangle construction tool as normal.  Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  This will put the ArcMap Rectangle tool into straight (horizontal/vertical) align mode.  It will stay in this mode for the Rectangle tool until you either press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again while using the tool, or you close ArcMap.

[image]

Because it stays in the straight mode you can just keep drawing new rectangles, so eliminates the need for the continuous key/button presses while you add more rectangles.  Even if you stop editing and come back to it later, it will still draw the straight rectangles.

See [Creating a rectangle feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-rectangle-feature.htm):

> - **Keyboard Shortcut: TAB**
>
>   Press TAB to orient the rectangle straight (vertical or horizontal at 90-degree angles) rather than rotated. This enters a mode where all the rectangles you create will be straight. Press TAB again to exit this mode and create rectangles with a rotation angle.

Comment: This is a useful tip! Will have to remember this one. It seems you already new the answer when you asked the question. ;)

Comment: @Matthew Actually no, I was half way through writing the question when I found the answer, so decided to finish the question and self-answer it

Comment: Nice, I did it through draw toolbar, very annoying